# Android - Listing buttons randomly

Tags: android, arrays, random, arraylist

I'm a newbie android programmer.

I'm tring to create a simple game.

**Game;**

Displaying a random number bettween 1 to 10, let's say it mainnumber.
Displaying 4 buttons.
First button value is mainnumber.
Second button value is mainnumber + 1
Third button value is mainnumber - 1
and The Last button value is mainnumber + 2

**How to play;**
If the user clicked correct button (mainnumber), it'll display another number and buttons.

**My Code;**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_easygame);

    Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer_one);
    Button b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer_two);
    Button b3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer_three);
    Button b4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer_four);

    Random number = new Random();
    int mainnumber = number.nextInt(10)+1;
    int rnd1 = mainnumber + 1;
    int rnd2 = mainnumber + 2;
    int rnd3 = mainnumber - 1;

    String a = Integer.toString(mainnumber);
    String b = Integer.toString(rnd1);
    String c = Integer.toString(rnd2);
    String d = Integer.toString(rnd3);


    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.display)).setText(Integer.toString(mainnumber));

    List<Button> buttons = Arrays.asList(b1, b2, b3, b4);
    List<String> texts = Arrays.asList(a, b, c, d);
    Random rand = new Random();
    buttons.get(rand.nextInt()).setText(texts.get(rand.nextInt()));
}
```

Getting system error, and app closing.

**Question;**
How can I display buttons randomly each time, and how can I check the clicked button is true button.

Thanks...

Comment: you need to show more of the logging and error message, but off hand i'd say you're getting some sort of OutofBoundsException since your Random object isn't bounded by anything and could return 8,675,309 which is larger than your texts array list.

Comment: @Dave It actually is bounded by 10.

Comment: this Random instance is not bounded: Random rand = new Random();
    buttons.get(rand.nextInt()).setText(texts.get(rand.nextInt()));

Comment: Oh, sure! Sorry. And that supports your suspicion.

Comment: yes, errors starting with java.lang.IndexOutofBoundsException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Collections.shuffle(texts);//shuffle the buttons
 //shuffle the buttons if you want as well, but whatever..
 int i = 0;
 //for loop moved below..
 /*
 for(Button button : buttons)
 {
     button.setText(texts.get(i++));
 }
 */
//custom android.view.View.OnClickListener instance.
OnClickListener onClick = new OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
         Button button = (Button) view;//safe cast since this is only added to buttons.
         String value = button.getText();
         //process button value..
    } 

};

for(Button button : buttons)
{
    button.setText(texts.get(i++));
    button.setOnClickListener(onClick);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. How can I control the correct button clicked?

Comment: kinda late, but what do you mean by "control the correct button clicked"?